# Problems with slider values in my React Component

Tags: reactjs, slider

I have a component that has a slider inside it, and I also have a container with a total price.

This slider has a step equal to one. I want to add ranges. For example :

- From 0 to 10, 0.2 should be added to the total price
- From 10 to 20, 0.4
- From 20 and beyond - 0.6.

Accordingly, when the slider moves to the right and the value of the slider increases, a certain value is added to the total price (0.2, 0.4, 0.6, etc.).

When to the left - is taken away.

The problem is that when the slider jumps from 9 to 10, 0.4 is added, and from 10 to 9, 0.2 is already subtracted. And it turns out an extra 0.2 to the total price, and when you return the slider to the value 0, the total price does not contain the same props .totalPrice value, but 0.2 more.

Further - if I click on some random value on the slider.

For example - 51, and then on 5, I will not get the value 101 (100 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 = 101), as if I moved from 0 to 5, and I will get a value greater than 110. And I need to set the ranges and some value that would be added or subtracted from the total price, depending on the movement of the slider, in these ranges.

Here is my component code:

```
import Slider from "rc-slider";
import './ContentSlider.css'
import ContentSliderCheckboxes from "./ContentSliderCheckboxes";
import AddCartModal from "../../Cart/AddCartModal/AddCartModal";

const ContentSlider = (props) => {

    const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(0);
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(props.totalPrice);

    const handleSliderChange = (value) => {
        const difference = value - sliderValue;
        setSliderValue(value);

        let priceChange = 0;

        if (value < 10) {
            priceChange = 0.2 * difference;
        } else if (value >= 10 && value < 20) {
            priceChange = 0.4 * difference;
        } else {
            priceChange = 0.6 * difference;
        }

        setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice + priceChange);
    };






        return (
        <div className={'productContentSliderContainer'}>
            <div>{sliderValue}</div>
            <div>{totalPrice}</div>
            <div className={'contentSliderContainer'}>
                <Slider
                    value={sliderValue}
                    min={0}
                    max={1000}
                    onChange={handleSliderChange}
                    step={1}
                    marks={
                        {
                            100: 100,
                            200: 200,
                            300: 300,
                            400: 400,
                            500: 'Diamond',
                            600: 'ML',
                            700: 'GML'
                        }
                    }
                    trackStyle={{backgroundColor: '#ffc107', transition: '0.1s'}}
                    handleStyle={{
                        backgroundColor: '#ffc107',
                        transition: '0.1s',
                        borderColor: '#ffc107',
                        opacity: 1,
                        boxShadow: '0 0 0 8px rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.5)'
                    }}
                    railStyle={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.3)'}}
                    dotStyle={{
                        top: '15px',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(33, 37, 41)',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(33, 37, 41)',
                        borderRadius: 0,
                        width: '2px',
                        height: '10px'
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div className={'productContentCheckboxesContainer'}>
                <ContentSliderCheckboxes
                    game={props.page}
                    product={props.product}
                    setPrice={props.setPrice}
                />
            </div>
            <div className={'customizeDividerLine'}></div>
            <div className={'contentSliderFooter'}>
                <div className={'contentSliderTotalPrice'}>
                    Total: {Number(totalPrice.toFixed(1))}&#8364;
                </div>
                <div className={'contentSliderButtonsContainer'}>
                    <button
                        className={'contentSliderButton contentSliderButtonBuy'}
                        onClick={() => props.addToCartHandler(sliderValue)}
                    >
                        Buy Now
                    </button>
                    <button
                        className={'contentSliderButton contentSliderButtonHelp'}
                    >
                        I have question
                    </button>
                </div>
                <AddCartModal show={props.showModal} setShowModal={props.setShowModal}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContentSlider;
```

I've tried a variety of ways. Tried not using difference value in handler, adding different conditions, but nothing helped